# PHP and mysql's binary log file

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am trying to recover the content of MySQL binary log file using PHP from the virtual machine I am running. I am running CentOS on the virtual machine and LAMP.

I have 4 virtual machines running on a virtual network, they are all located on the same subnet and the MySQL databases are up and running and the replication is working.

I am trying to recover the content of the master's bin log using PHP. Normally the content of the file can be recovered using the following command:

```
shell> mysqlbinlog [options] log_file
```

I have written a PHP script that executes a shell command on the local machine:

```
$cmd="mysqlbinlog /var/lib/mysql/provider-bin.000003";
echo "<pre>".shell_exec($cmd);
```

I have checked that the provider-bin.000003 exists and that the shell_exec function works and is not disabled.

The problem takes place when I execute the command on the console I get the content of the bin file, but the PHP script does not output the expected result.

It's outputting the following instead:

```
/*!40019 SET @@session.max_insert_delayed_threads=0*/;
/*!50003 SET @OLD_COMPLETION_TYPE=@@COMPLETION_TYPE,COMPLETION_TYPE=0*/;
DELIMITER /*!*/;
DELIMITER ;
# End of log file
ROLLBACK /* added by mysqlbinlog */;
/*!50003 SET COMPLETION_TYPE=@OLD_COMPLETION_TYPE*/;
```

**Update: exec**

I have also tried using the exec function adn it outputs the same:

```
$cmd="mysqlbinlog /var/lib/mysql/provider-bin.000003";

print_r(exec($cmd,$ret_value)) . "<br />DONE";

echo "<pre>".shell_exec($cmd." 2>&1");
```

Much appreciated

Comment: Does the file / directory you're interested in have the appropriate permissions to allow the PHP / Apache user to access it? Note that running the command line in a console is not necessarily the same as having PHP do the same thing for you (the PHP user may not be allowed to do what you can from the console).

Comment: I execute the PHP script as a cron job so it should have root rights. I am testing the permissions at the moment using the whoami command. I will give it a go and if the problem originates from there then I will delete this question.

Comment: You don't necessarily need to delete the question. Feel free to answer your own question if you like ... that way people who have a similar problem in the future will know what to do.

Comment: Will do if I figure it out I will post the solution ;-)

Comment: Have you tried running shell_exec("/usr/bin/mysqlbinlog /var/lib/mysql/provider-bin.000003 > /home/binlog.out"); ? Redirecting the output to a file can probably point you to the source of the problem. Also remember to View Source if you are outputting to a browser, since you are actually seeing HTML :) .

Comment: Is there anything output to `stderr`?

Comment: I have published what the script is outputting in my post, its under "It's outputting the following instead:". I have solved the problem yesterday evening but did not have the time to post the solution yet as I have been working like crazy (Circular replciation is wrong on so many levels). I will try to post the solution during my lunch break. Thank you guys anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured it out a couple of days agon, so here is the solution.

Although mysqlbinlog gets executed by PHP it is still not able to read MySQL's binary files if run from a browser, for some reason it shows file does not exists. That was never my plan, so a cron job and sh file did the trick for me.

Cron job will run the script as a root without explosing its content to the outside world.

Now my circular replication failover script is running happily.